# I have entered machine name in a textbox, However now that i want to replace it with an empty string, it's not being replaced

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox

Following is the code snip

```
private void pname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PcName = System.Environment.MachineName;
    pname.Text = PcName;
}
```

I want to clear the pname textbox on click of cancel button.

Comment: Please show us your event handler for clicking of the cancel button.

Comment: the name suggests you have this run when the text is changed; why not just run such method on page load? (so it's only set once)

Comment: As the others have said, you need to put the "replace with empty string" logic in your Cancel Button event.  Also, the initial setting of this value should be done in the Page Load event instead of the Text Change.  Think about it, you want your text to change every time your text changes?

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked